# HOW CAN I ADD onTap method for custom listview menu

Tags: flutter

I have an horizontal listview and i want to add click listener for all items which is in listview where should i use onTap method?

[this is food_cart.dart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeYXe.png)

[This is food category.dart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcuMB.png)

[app screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66wDu.png)

Comment: Please post the real code and not the screenshot of it.

Comment: where does the foodCard coming from where is the code?. also you can wrap foodcard to `gestureDetector`, it has onTap,onDoubleTap methods. [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html)

Comment: its coming from there final categories = [
  Category(
      categoryName: ("Burger"),
      imagePath: "android/assets/images/burger.png",
      numberOfItems: 43,),

Comment: You can use Inkwell, child of ListView, and please add more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use GestureDetector or InkWell. GestureDetector is useful to provide many other gestures like onHorizontalDragDown, onVerticalDragDown etc. While Inkwell is useful to provide ripple effect for the child widget.

```
InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          //Perform your logic here
        }
        child:YOUR_LISTVIEW_ITEM,
)
```

**OR**

```
GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          //Perform your logic here
        }
        child:YOUR_LISTVIEW_ITEM,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `FoodCard` inside an [Inkwell](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html),

```
InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          //navigate to screen or show a dialog or do anything
          Navigator.pushNamed(
              context, '/PostDetailsScreen', arguments: mFeedData);
        }
child:YOUR_FOOD_CARD,
)
```